# Primefaces datatable new/delete a row with partial update

Tags: primefaces

When adding/deleting a row, is it common to update the entire table to refresh it, such as `update="form:tbl"` ?

Is there any method to update only the added/deleted row and not the entire table ?

I'm using `Primefaces 5.3`.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" update="form:tbl" actionListener="#{myService.add()}" process="@this"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in the official documentation there is the feature you requested
[Datatable - Add Row](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/addRow.xhtml), but is seems available only on Primefaces 6.0 milestone, see [addRow() method to DataTable](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1169).
You can try with a paginated datatable, so when you add the new row, you have to update and display only the last page of the component.

Comment: You're right. addRow() is a new feature, but not supported in v5.3. And I have to discuss this(with a paginated datatable) with my customer.